# Time Series Rolling Regression on Stacked data

Tags: matlab, time-series

#### Data Format:

[image]

I have unbalanced panel data (in `FUNDNO` column) for 4,435 panels. The panels are in rows as data, collected from CRSP. [See the Data Sample in mat file given here](https://shorturl.at/ahlB2).

I need to do time series rolling regression (window=36 months) for each panel (1, 38, ....) using the available time series. I tried to implement the following code. However, I am getting an error message:

> Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 1).

My code is as follows:

```
yr = fix(Date(:, 1)/10000) ;
mt = mod(fix(Date(:, 1)/100), 100) ;

t = datetime(yr, mt, 1) ;

clear yr mt

  
w0 = 36 ; % Initial sample: 1989/01-1991/12(36 months)
wT = 132 - w0 + 1 ; % # of sample from Rolling Regression 
Index = unique(FUNDNO);
N = length(Index);

list = groupcounts(FUNDNO,Index);

bff = [TERM,DEF,SENTL];

intercept = zeros(wT,N);
betasTERM = zeros(wT,N);
betasDEF = zeros(wT,N);
betasSENTL = zeros(wT,N);



%Time series regression we estimate the betas
for n = 1 : N
    
    for i=1:wT
        
        reg1 = fitlm(bff(i : i+w0-1, :), ER(i : i+w0-1, n)) ;
        intercept(wT,n) = reg1.Coefficients.Estimate(1);
        betasTERM(wT,n) = reg1.Coefficients.Estimate(2);
        betasDEF(wT,n) = reg1.Coefficients.Estimate(3);
        betasSENTL(wT,n) = reg1.Coefficients.Estimate(4);    
    end
    
end
```

Comment: Your code cannot be run because `FUNDNO`, `TERM`, `DEF` and `Return` are not given. Please provide data for these variables or add at the beginning of your script the generation of random matrices with correct shape. For instance if `FUNDNO` is a 1400x3 matrix, add `FUNDNO=rand(1400,3);` at the beginning. The code will then be executable and it will be possible to help you.

Comment: @bousof I have provided the data in the following link https://shorturl.at/ahlB2 and updated the code which i was trying. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Anis, I'm sorry I can't run your code because of a problem of version I'm using R2014a and it's too old. I think your error comes from `ER(i : i+w0-1, n)` that you should replace by `ER(i : i+w0-1, 1)` because in the dataset you provided, `ER` is a column vector. You may also replace want to replace indexes `(wT,n)` by `(i,n)` in the FOR loops to save all your rolling regression coeffficients. Good luck !

Comment: @I replaced n by 1. Regression was run with no error but I have not got my results. The main issue that I am trying to share is, usually panel data are in columns for each column. In my case, panels are in row. [See attached image for structure]. My panels have an unbalanced observation. I have not dealt with regression on such data structure and have not found such example in any site too. If you can assist me on this issue, i believe I can solve my issue.